(IMPORTANT) i dont know if i committed shirk or not
Assalamu alaikum, im mot sure if i committed shirk or not and i couldnt find the answer to my question anywhere.Today i was looking at someones profile on social media and i really liked their takes on topics so i made this sign  to symbolize were locked in together as a joke and this sign is also used by christians to symbolize “jesus Protection” (astaghfirullah) so did i commit shirk? i don’t know what to do.

Well in 99% of the cases one asks in the manner you've done the answer is simply: No, because without intention an act of any kind can hardly be regarded as valid and once you are in doubt you can't have an intention. We have two reference questions which tell you what is shirk and what is kufr the answers of both should cover all kinds of possibilities available: see What is shirk in Islam? and Is "X" kufr reference question

Well no, you didnt committed shirk, because you didnt knew that sign meant something else accidents are forgiven in Islam, and if you still use that sign without symbolizing jesus protection, i think it still wont be considered as shirk because you used it for something else with pure intentions.
